# Meaning of “Se necesita señorita”

Tags: género, significado-en-contexto

In Peru, I’ve been seeing job ads saying variants of “Se necesita señorita” to indicate they need some sort of waitress, shop assistant etc. I know that they’re merely looking for someone young rather than unmarried, but do they literally only want women, or men as well and they avoid “señorito” because it connotes someone rather useless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Señorito' no es el masculino de señorita. Varias acepciones posee cada uno de los términos, pero las que más usé y he oído son:

> **[Señorita](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/se%C3%B1orita)**. Mujer núbil y soltera

> **[Señorito](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/se%C3%B1orito)**. Persona excesivamente fina y remilgada.

Así que, por una parte, 'señorito' suele ser despectivo sobre todo porque hay una expresión que es 'hacerse el señorito inglés' usada cuando alguien aparenta ser más 'aristocrático' de lo que es.

Y por otra parte, justamente están buscando 'señoritas' y por eso no eligen una palabra neutra (como 'empleado'). En otros tiempos habían trabajos exclusivos para mujeres o para hombres, pero hoy diría que ese aviso es favoritista hacia un género—y, en teoría, cabría una denuncia.